# Is there a scale with a usb interface for tracking data?

Tags: brewing-process

Instead of manually writing down the brew process I try each day (example: 18g beans, 40g water @ 0:00; 180g water @ 0:45; etc), I would love my scale to be connected directly to my computer. Then I can just pour water (using a pour over on the scale) and my computer automatically tracked the data. I'm a programmer, so I have zero problems writing a program to collect the data, and then even present a UI with a form where I can rate the taste of it.

The problem is that I can't find a good scale that has a usb interface to the computer. And even the few I find that say "usb", it only mentioned it for power supply, not computer interfacing.

Does such a scale exist?

Answer (score 1):

So  I just found this: [https://www.amazon.com/Acaia-Scale-AP001-Scale-Pearl/dp/B018RN7EP0/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1541702297&sr=8-3&keywords=acaia+pearl](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B018RN7EP0) which comes with a phone app to track the data. I don't know if this allows me to programmatically pull that data into my own personal database though.

Comment: If there exists a connection, you can parse the data somehow. In the worst case scenario, you can capture the packets on the air or hook system calls to the app. The question (or trade-off) is how much time do you want to spend on it. Maybe, you can check lab equipment instead of kitchen equipment. Normally, producers of utensils assume a regular person in the kitchen does not require a data connection. But, researchers use such data everyday. E.g. I found this from Mettler by such a serach: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0U5tjoRow4o)